# В каких случаях используются следующие слова?

Tags: этимология

Pro et contra, dixi, credo, c'est la vie, ergo.

Интересно просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с конца. Ergo - значит, соответственно. Знаменитое высказывание Декарта, "я мыслю, следовательно я существую" на латыни звучит "cogito, ergo sum". C'est la vie - французское "это жизнь", "такова жизнь", сравнимо с русским "такова судьба". Используется, когда человек признаёт какой-то недостаток, но понимает, что ничего с этим поделать нельзя. "Нужны Парижу деньги - c'est la vie!" - то есть, что ж я могу с этим сделать? Ничего. Такова судьба, что денег нет. Credo - "я верю" (лат.), сравнимо с английским "creed" (вероисповедание, догма). Означает систему веры, философии, и других убеждений. "Он не может построить свою карьеру потому что в наше время живёт с старомодным credo", "В этой молодой стране ещё не сформировалось устойчивое политическое credo". Dixi - "я сказал" (лат.), подразумевает не сказанное: "я всё сказал, разговор окончен". Pro et contra означает и используется как "за и против".

Надеюсь, что я понятно ответила!

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Кое-что новое узнал. Вопрос: можно ли использовать эти слова в русских текстах? =)

Comment: @Tagirix: "C'est la vie" встречала и в русских, и в английских текстах. В русском видела "кредо", но ни разу не видела чтобы это слово было написанно латинскими буквами. Ergo иногда используется в английском, но в русском не встречала. Остальные тоже не видела в текстах, но я думаю что иногда можно бы и блеснуть знанием латыни. :)

Comment: А Вы знаете?

Comment: @Tagirix: Если бы! :) Нет, к сожалению не знаю, но коллекционирую пёстрые фразы.